# Why does the variable name in my imported dataset have random characters added to it?

Tags: r, xlsx, readxl

It's a bit tricky to provide a reproducible example, but my issue is that I am bringing in a dataset of British Geological Society mineral production data (after some slight tidying in Excel).

Specifically, from [this website](https://www2.bgs.ac.uk/mineralsuk/statistics/wms.cfc?method=searchWMS) I'm downloading a .xlsx of production data for the diamond commodity from 2010 - 2020 by all countries.

When I bring it into R via readxl, the first column name has random characters appended to it -- so instead of `Country`, it reads `\r\n\tCountry`.

From poking around at other answers, I feel like this could be some strange SQL artifact in the original dataset (?), and I read that you could set readxl with specific encoding to prevent this, but it seems like readxl doesn't take that argument anymore.

My code:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(readxl)

# Set working directory.--------------------------------------------------------

setwd("Filepath/Project")

# Load data.--------------------------------------------------------------------

df <- read_xlsx("Filepath/Diamond Datasheet.xlsx")
```

And the head(df) output:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 12
  `\r\n\tCountry`   `2010`   `2011`   `2012`   `2013`   `2014`   `2015`   `2016`   `2017`  `2018` `2019` `2020`
  <chr>              <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1 Angola           8362139  8328519  8330996  8601696  8791340  9018942  9021767  9438802  8.41e6 9.15e6 7.73e6
2 Australia        9997752  7561487  8625996 11481749  9288118 13560795 13958000 17135000  1.40e7 1.22e7 9.98e6
3 Botswana        22019000 22903000 20478000 22597000 24658000 20824000 20954000 22900000  2.74e7 2.37e7 1.69e7
4 Brazil             25394    45536    46292    49166    56923    31826   183500   254896  2.51e5 1.66e5 1.25e5
5 Cameroon            6000     6000     5000     5000     6000     4500     3000     3500  3.6 e3 3.5 e3 4.2 e3
6 Canada          11773000 10795000 10529215 10561600 12082000 11677472 11103500 23198761  2.28e7 1.85e7 1.50e7
```

The `\r\n\tCountry` bit is the weird part to me. Many thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what the issue is. The name of the variable is probably not proper for R to read in. Judging by the variable names this is the case, as you can see the years are quoted as *'Year'* instead of *Year*. Variables that start with numbers or have odd spacing cause R to poop itself. Thankfully you can easily change the name with the `rename` function in the `tidyverse` package. As an example:

```
#### Library ####
library(tidyverse)

#### Make Column of Country Data ####
df <- data.frame(Weird.Name = c("America",
                                "Japan",
                                "Russia"))
df
```

This data frame also has a poor name:

```
  Weird.Name
1    America
2      Japan
3     Russia

#### Rename ####
df %>% 
  rename(Country = Weird.Name)
```

Now it doesnt :)

```
  Country
1 America
2   Japan
3  Russia
```

Just as a sidenote...variable names are best if they are in this format before importing: `Variable.Name` or `Variable_Name`.